# In R, how do I assign value from adjacent top column if cell is null

Tags: r, null, na

I normally do this in Excel but it's becoming cumbersome now.  In R, how do I assign the adjacent top column value if cell in dataframe is null?

For example, if dataframe/table is like this:

```
1,2,3

4,5,6

7,null,9


10,11,null
```

I want it to become:

```
1,2,3

4,5,6

7,5,9

10,11,9
```

Thanks in advance. Step-by-step code is always appreciated (apologies I'm more of a BA rather than a programmer)

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you're working with `NA` values, not `NULL` values (since I don't think you can have `NULL` values like that in a `data.frame` unless it's an actual character string like `"null"`).

Here's some sample data:

```
mydf <- data.frame(V1 = c(1, 3, 7, 10), 
                   V2 = c(2, 5, NA, 11), 
                   V3 = c(3, 6, 9, NA))
mydf
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  1  2  3
# 2  3  5  6
# 3  7 NA  9
# 4 10 11 NA
```

Here's a quick solution using `na.locf` from the "zoo" package.

```
library(zoo)

na.locf(mydf)
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  1  2  3
# 2  3  5  6
# 3  7  5  9
# 4 10 11  9
```

Comment: Also `na.locf(mydf, fromLast = TRUE)` would fill in NAs with the next non-NA value rather than the previous.

Answer (score 1):

Use `na.locf` from zoo package. Consider your data is called `dat` and replace your `null` with `NA`

```
> dat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7   NA    9
[4,]   10   11   NA
> library(zoo)
> na.locf(dat)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    5    9
[4,]   10   11    9
```

Answer (score 1):

And a longer version using base R functions...

```
> d
##   V1 V2 V3
## 1  1  2  3
## 2  4  5  6
## 3  7 NA  9
## 4 10 11 NA
> as.data.frame(t(sapply(seq(nrow(d)), function(i){
      ifelse(is.na(d[i, ]), d[i-1, ], d[i, ])
      })))
##   V1 V2 V3
## 1  1  2  3
## 2  4  5  6
## 3  7  5  9
## 4 10 11  9
```